# Absolute continuity of DOS measure for Schrödinger operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

Kotani theory gives roughly that for ergodic operators there is a certain equivalence between absolutely continuous spectrum and an absolutely continuous density of states measure.

I would like to ask whether this is also true in the "opposite case", i.e. given a periodic Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+V$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (by this I mean that the potential is periodic):

Is it true that if this operator has purely absolutely continuous spectrum (which is always true in dimension $1$), then the DOS measure is absolutely continuous?- It somehow sounds very reasonable but I fail to see from what it should follow exactly?

Comment: I think that's clear, modulo (perhaps annoying) technical problems; it would be easier in the discrete setting probably. You can obtain the DOS by averaging spectral measures, and periodicity means that the averaging is over a compact set (it would be a finite one in the discrete case) of measures which are assumed absolutely continuous themselves.

Comment: By the way, absolute continuity of the spectrum has been established under very general assumptions, see here for example: https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/2001/1/1/662724?redirectedFrom=PDF

Comment: @ChristianRemling thank you, I understand. May I ask you a follow-up questions from what you wrote: If the potential is nice, can we assume that the DOS function has then also some regularity besides $L^1_{\text{loc}}$?-This also seems natural to me, but I am not aware of any results.  And thank you for the reference, this results looks very interesting to me.

Comment: Yes, that definitely sounds to me like it has to be true, but of course I also have to warn you that I'm certainly no expert on higher-dimensional operators.